# Blender 2.8 Freestyle SVG exporter broken?

Tags: export, freestyle, svg

I'm trying to create line drawings from my model (which I have done many, MANY times before), but the new version is not working how I'm used to. Yesterday it was creating the freestyle lines in the render, but exporting blank SVG files. Today, it's gotten worse, and is not rendering any freestyle lines nor outputting any usable SVG files (all blank with a size of 1KB).

I have tried Cycles and Eevee, both with no luck. I've moved my objects to a new Blender file, restarted my computer, reinstalled Blender, all with no luck.

Also, the freestyle calculations are taking much MUCH longer than I'm used to, just to give me nothing in the end. Each time I render it takes 30-45 minutes to output a blank render window and a blank SVG file.

I can't post photos of my objects because of non-disclosure agreements, but if it helps, they are simple flat surfaces in various shapes, with holes for screws and such as well as freestyle edge marks for a few interior lines. I also have a plain cube which does the same: nada.

I've gone through all of the freestyle and SVG export options, and cannot identify a single one that could be causing this. I'm using all the same settings that I used in 2.79, and have also been playing with the settings to see if they change anything but no luck at all with anything.

So what changed? I know its a difficult question to ask when I can't post any images, but are there any newer settings I need to mess with to make this work again? I can't find any other posts with this issue and I need this to work ASAP.

I know this community loves its screenshots, but I hope I've provided enough information for suggestions. Let me know what you guys think is going on here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you used Blender 2.8 before and it worked properly (or did it only work in 2.79)? Have you tried a simple scene like the default cube in Blender 2.8 and what were the results?

Comment: It has only worked in 2.79, since updating to 2.8 it does not work. Yes, I have tried the default cube, and it did not do anything differently. I would really like to make it work in 2.8 rather than reverting, I'm very interested in trying the new curvature computation.

Comment: So even with the default cube no freestyle lines in the render and also an empty svg export? You're using the official release of Blender 2.8?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've even tried reinstalling and it didn't help. :(

Comment: Do you get any render results at all without having freestyle active (*Render Tab > Freestyle*) since you're saying that with freestyle the render is blank? Are there any errors written on the console?

Comment: Yes, when I have environment and surfaces turned on all of those things render properly. With or without freestyle on. SVG is still blank though. I have freestyle enabled in render settings, filter settings in layers tab, and Freestyle SVG export enabled in scene settings. But weird thing that just happened, I just had to reenable the SVG export addon in user preferences and noticed that it keeps disabling itself. Is there a way to set default user settings in 2.8, or is that supposed to happen automatically? Still doesn't explain why it would be exporting blank SVG files though.

Comment: Update: Just tried it on a different work computer, which was working normally for the most part, until I enabled face marks. Then it started doing the same things that happen on my work computer. I tried disabling face marks on my computer so after its finished doing its thing we'll see if it worked. The render itself is finished but its still taking a ridiculous amount of time to calculate the freestyle lines, so I sort of doubt it helped.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue on my end, it works both with and without *Mark Freestyle Edge*. I know that the SVG exporter has an error that prevents it from showing what used to be the render layer options in Blender 2.79 because the `bl_context` wasn't updated (https://developer.blender.org/rBA9e0dc9b9d3c4c83eee207324ea9df0bf6e619617). That shouldn't be the cause though, especially if you're experiencing this with the default cube (and not just with old projects from 2.79).

Comment: If you find a reliable way to reproduce the issue on both computers, please write a bug report (*Help > Report a bug* in Blender and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4) and include step by step instructions how to create a project where this problem occurs.

Comment: I'm using 2.82 now and I also cannot get the Freestyle SVG Exporter to produce anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue with Freestyle SVG exporter. I thought I was getting empty SVG file each time I was rendering. I tried on Cube scene with almost default setting and it worked, but after importing a mesh from FBX file Freestyle seems to be creating just an empty file. After few days of playing around with different settings still no results.

Then one day, I noticed that my CPU usage is not high but it was not equal to 0% when the render was already done - at least it seems like it was done.

[image: CPU usage was still not 0%]

Then I noticed that there is a small information from freestyle that in renderer window:

[image: freestyle svg export still running]

It seems that the SVG pass was still working in the background. After some time around 1 hour it produced the SVG output correctly. I think the plugin could use a little bit better way of communicating that it is still processing the SVG, especially that when closing the Rendered window it is aborting the process. I almost lost my hair over this.

TIP 1: Selecting option to cache the View Map can save a lot of time if you trying out different output styling, but I would recommend working out the Line Style on a very simple object first before going into rendering the complex mesh, or a scene.

TIP 2: Selecting "Select by Image Border" also saves a lot of time if we have a complex scene and what we have actually in the camera view is just a part of all.

I know it is an old post, but maybe will save time for many people in the future. Best regards.